# What event handler do I need to use for a drop down menu list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, event-handling

I need to make an event handler to run my function each time a new item is selected from a drop down menu list.

So far I have tried "onselect", "onclick", "onmousedown", and "onblur" and none of these seem to work. What is the value needed to update each time someone selects a new item from the drop down menu list or the same item, for that matter?

Comment: `onchange` and maybe `oninput`?

Comment: You want to use `onchange`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use an [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event handler, you can implement this with diffrent methods. The first one is to write the event directly in your **html** `select` tag:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

Use **Javascript** only:

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

mySelect.onchange = function() {
   var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
 }
```

```html
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

---

Or you can use **jQuery**:

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
    $("#demo").html("You selected: " + this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Alternatively for **jQuery** you can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```js
$("#mySelect").on("change", function() {
    $("#demo").html("You selected: " + this.value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try on onchange event handler. That will call the method every time the selection is being change.[Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about dropdown menu list, which can be created with a variety of html elements, if you are using 'select' then you must use onchange event, but if you're using an unordered list or something else you must use onclick for the list item

Answer (score 0):

You need to use on change and the reason is why you are changing the value of an input form element: [Check This example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange)